# MsgBox to confirm end of a run

Tags: vba, popup, messagebox, msgbox, xlsm

I'd like to insert a MsgBox at the end of a run in order to inform script is done.
Using this code I've got the message even if the run is still going.
Would anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

```
Sub UPDATE_db_pivot() 'Variable Declaration
        Msgbox "Ricorda di aggiornare le date del 'Periodo di Osservazione' presenti nel foglio 'Cover'", vbExclamation
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Sheets("DIREZIONE Summary").Select
        ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
        Range("C85").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
        Sheets("PRB_DataBase").Select
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("E270").Select
        Msgbox "Aggiornamento completato!", vbInformation 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved unchecking the background refresh data to disable it.